# Where and how to install dependent binaries and libs with a Python application

Tags: python, distutils

I have a Python application with which I would like to distribute a command line binary and its dependent libs. My application shells out to this binary, so I need to know where it and its libs are.

Up to now licensing was an issue and the party installing my app had to get this utility separately, and the assumption that `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib` (or similar) were used was working just fine. The licensing issue has been cleared up (yay!) but now I need to manage this, and I wonder if there's a standard practice and/or if there's a way to have distutils do it for me. Should I still be sending the files to standard locations? Or should they go to, e.g. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/{My_app}/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PythonDocs suggest:

`/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` for [system-wide](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#standard-build-and-install) installations (Unix) and:

`userbase/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` for [user-based](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme) installations, where userbase in my case (Linux) is `$HOME/.local`.

Regarding compiled extensions, they normaly end in `$PREFIX/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload` and executable scripts under `$PREFIX/bin`(Linux).

Normaly this kind of stuff gets handled by your distutil-package. Just write a correct `setup.py` file and most of this stuff gets handled automagically.

The only draw-back is, that the future of python-packaging is not really definite atm and documentation is somewhat confussing and not up to date.

A good startin point is probably: [Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/)

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking, but is it true (does it matter?) even when the binaries aren't Python? So I'd have /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/{my_app}/bin /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/{my_app}/lib ?

Comment: It's not a compiled extension to Python, it's really separate stand alone application to which I shell out with the subprocess module, so it feels strange to me to have it outside of my application, but I'm seeing other libs that look like they may not be python-specific in`/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/` so I guess I can do the same in `/usr/local/...`.

Comment: Are you including a license-server? Then maybe an installation into /usr/local could conflict with another license-server! We had an issue with updates of a specific FEM-Software a long time ago! In this case you may consider installing the program into your package script-folder?!

Comment: No license server involved; that would be a nightmare! Even though it's non-standard (if there is a standard) and hacky, I'm thinking that using `package_data=` in my setup call and keeping them right with the package might be the easiest. I don't like it, but it does seem safest.

Comment: Alternatively consider the `data_files`-argument. `package_data` is under your package-directory! e.g. `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/mypackage/data/mybinary`